# drop down menu doesn't do what i want

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

hi i am working on a site layout , because of my problem and for some other reasons like that it doesn't matter to me if i just can use the layout on my own as well cause i made it.
but the problem is that the pulldown menu isn't working as it is mend to be.

i share with you the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,#013,#c0c);
    color:#930;
}
#nav{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:40px;
    maring-bottom:10px;
    color:#930;
    background-color:#cb6;
    border:2px solid #930;
    border-radius:13px;
    -webkit-border-radius:13px;
    -moz-border-radius:13px;
    text-align:center;
    float:center;
    width:750px;
    height:40px;
}
#main{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:auto;
    maring-bottom:auto;
    color:#930;
    background-color:#cb6;
    border:2px solid #930;
    border-radius:13px;
    -webkit-border-radius:13px;
    -moz-border-radius:13px;
    text-align:center;
    float:center;
    width:750px;
    height:500px;
}
#nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#nav li{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
#nav a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#930;
    padding:10px 25px;
    height:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#nav a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#930;
    padding:10px 25px;
    height:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#pull li ul{
    display:none;
    color:#930;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
}
#pull li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    color:#930;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
}
#pull li ul a{
    display:block;
    min-width:80px;
    width:auto;
    height:25px;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0px 5px;
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid #930;
    background-color:#cb6;
}
#pull li ul a:hover{
    display:block;
    min-width:80px;
    width:auto;
    height:25px;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0px 5px;
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    background-color:#930;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
<ul id="pull">
    <li><a href="http://www.elderpact.site11.com/home.html"><b>home</b></a></li>&nbsp&nbsp
    <li><a href="http://www.elderpact.site11.com/page.html"><b>page 1 &#9660</b></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.elderpact.site11.com/page2.html"><b>page 2</b></a><li>
            <li><a href="http://www.elderpact.site11.com/page3.html"><b>page 3</b></a><li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="main">
de content komt nog
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

also the online lay-out is see-able for eyes at www.elderpact.tk

the menu bar and everything need to stay like they are
but the drop down menu has to lower the content box if it is opened.
now it goes right trough the content.
also i would like to display the drop down menu direct under the drop down menu opener
(page 1).

could someone please help me?

Comment: another note: you may use this lay out if you want, but please don't claim this of being your own design. i want to use it cause i made it but if someone else want's to use it i got no problem with that

Answer (score 0):

the risk with create you own dropdown is not work in all browsers. The best solution for this problem is use Bootstrap Twitter. [Bootstrap DropDown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-example)

Comment: sorry i might've been unclear but i can't use that cause that would affect the layout. it doesn't bother to me it won't work in all layouts.

Comment: the thing is it has to stay like it is just the dropdown has to go beneath li that spawns it and it doesn't may go trough content like it goes now

Comment: This is a terrible answer. <IE7 are the only browsers affected by some incompatibilities.

Comment: p.s. layouts-->browsers. cause i want the layout or the way it works to stay the same but i want that it doesn't overwrite the content

Comment: and it has to go beneath li with arrow thing not s.e. of it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle with the menu the way I **think** you want it: http://jsfiddle.net/TPLJ8/1/

You basically need to remove the margin and padding from the `ul` and `li` elements at the top of your CSS (resets), like this:

`ul, li {margin:0; padding:0;}`

This will help you start with a clean slate. I also cleaned up your CSS as you don't need to declare the same styling on `hovers` if that style stays the same.

Your HTML also needed some work. You were missing closing `</li>` tags and had a bunch of unnecessary `<br />` tags.

Comment: hey can you check www.elderpact.tk  page 1?

Comment: that is like the menu i wanted but i don't know how i got it.